# Header for HTTP/1 compression in PUT / POST request

Tags: http, post, header

When receiving gzipped data for a HTTP GET request the response header shows this by the field `Content-Encoding`. What is the correct way in a HTTP POST / HTTP PUT request to indicate what the request is sending gzipped data?

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields the request header does not know the `Content-Encoding` field. So how does the receiver know which compressing method is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content-Encoding is both a request and response header field, and gzip content encoding can indeed be used both in requests and responses. And yes, it may fail in requests if the server doesn't process the header field correctly. (That would be a bug in the server, though).

Further reading: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7694.html

Comment: _"(not sure what exactly on the Wikipedia page got you confused)"_ - on that page, the `Content-Encoding` header is only listed under "Response fields -> Standard response fields".

Comment: Aha, that's a bug. Will fix.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I see in the RFC 2616 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) it is not restricted to the response header, so you are right it is a bug and I can use it also on the request header.

@Julian Reschke: Thanks for fixing the Wiki page as well.

Comment: Yes, but note that 2616 isn't relevant anymore. You need to look at RFC 7231.